# Anomalies in date data

Tags: date, plsql

I have a dataset where there is a column titled 'Document_Date' which is currently formatted as VARCHAR. The dates in this column are mostly in DDMMYYYY format except for 197 rows where the date is in a weird format that looks something like this '0116-11-26'.

I'm currently having trouble mapping this data as the to_date function comes up with the error 'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected' which I suspect is because of the dash in the date. I've also tried using a Case statement to map the anomalies as to_date('0016-10-19', 'YYYYMMDD') and everything else as 'DDMMYYYY' but this comes up with the same error.

Is there a way for me to convert these anomalous dates into the format 'DDMMYYYY' (i.e. if the date was '0116-11-26' this would convert it to 26/11/0116) and convert all the correctly formatted dates as DD/MM/YYYY?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use a different format mask for those rare dates in a different format.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(col, '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
         THEN TO_DATE(col, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
         ELSE TO_DATE(col, 'DDMMYYYY')
    END AS new_date
FROM yourTable
```

As for why your current attempt to convert the `'0016-10-19'` date is failing, you may be using the wrong format mask.  You should be using the mask `YYYY-MM-DD`, *with* hyphens, when calling `TO_DATE()`.